# SketchUp + Vray - black background instead of transparent in png image

Tags: sketchup

I am trying to place a png picture in a SketchUp model. When rendering, the transparent background becomes black. As I understand it, this is a problem with the Alpha channel. Tell me, how can I fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please, help!!!

Comment: Based on the two images you have posted, it's clear that SketchUp is understanding the alpha channel in your placed `.png` without trouble - VRAY is where it's choking, Have you carefully set up your VRAY material to read and use that alpha channel? I'd start looking there.

Comment: I did not configure anything in Vray. This appeared immediately after the first picture. I will try to find.